# implicit derivative of $\ln(xy)=\cos(x)-8y^2$

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

Consider the equation

$$\ln(xy)=\cos(x)-8y^2$$

Now I thought the first step should be to raise everything to $e$ to get rid of the natural $\log$ but  by doing that will only complicate the problem even more.

So instead I found the derivative of $\ln(xy)$ which is

$$\frac{dy}{dx} \ln(xy)= \frac{x+y^{'}}{xy}$$
Then finding the derivative of the 2nd term yeilds

$$\frac{dy}{dx}\cos(x)-8y^2=-\sin(x)-16y y^{'}$$

Then setting both of them equal to each other, like in the original equation gives

$$\frac{x+y^{'}}{xy}=-\sin(x)-16yy^{'}$$ 
But now I am lost on how to isolate $y^{'}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
d\ln(xy)=d\cos x - 8d(y^2),\\
\frac{dx}{x}+\frac{dy}y=-(\sin x)dx-16ydy,\\
\frac1x+\frac{y'}y=-\sin x-16yy'
$$

Now let's collect all terms with $y'$ on one side:
$$
\frac{y'}y+16yy'=-\sin x-\frac 1x,\\
y'\frac{1+16y^2}{y}=-\frac{1+x\sin x}x,\\
y'=-\frac yx\frac{1+x\sin x}{1+16y^2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of $\log (xy)$ is not quite right. You should have instead $$\frac{1}{xy}(xy)'=\frac{1}{xy}(y+xy').$$ Your derivative for RHS is correct, but the notation is bad.

Finally, set the two sides equal and solve for $y',$ which of course denotes the derivative of $y$ with regard to $x.$